# Find all points on the XY plane where parabola doesn't pass

Tags: quadratics, parametric

Find all points on the XY plane where parabola $y=x^2-4px+2p^2-3$ doesn't pass. Note that $P\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer below

> $y<-x^2$

Deep explanation would be awesome because I can't do anything in this problem.

Comment: For each fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $$p \mapsto x^2-4px+2p^2-3 = 2(p-x)^2-x^2-3 $$ takes values exactly in $[-x^2-3,\infty)$. So the set of all points $(x,y)$ at which none of the parabolas $y=x^2-4px+2p^2-3$ for $p\in\mathbb{R}$ pass is given by the inequality $y<-x^2-3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^2-4px+2p^2-3$$Suppose $(a,b)$ is a point the parabola cannot pass through for any value of $p$. We want to find the locus of this point. Consider the equation $$f(a)=b \\ a^2-4pa+2p^2-3=b \\ 2p^2-4pa+a^2-b-3=0$$ The condition is that this quadratic in $p$  should have *no* solution, i.e. for any value of $b$ there should be no value of $a$ such that this equation holds for any $p$.  $$ D\lt 0 \\ \implies16a^2-8(a^2-b-3)\lt 0 \\ \implies b\lt -a^2-3$$ I believe the answer you gave has a typo.